# When to use for-each and when to use apply-templates in xslt?

Tags: xslt

I've heard that most of the time it's usually possible (and better) to use apply-templates rather than for-each when writing an XSLT.  Is this true?  If so, what are the benefits of using apply-templates?

Comment: Good question, this goes to the "heart" of XSLT. +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using `<xsl:for-each>` is in no way harmful if one knows exactly how an `<xsl:for-each>` is processed**.

The trouble is that a lot of newcomers to XSLT that have experience in imperative programming take `<xsl:for-each>` as a substitute of a "loop" in their favorite PL and think that it allows them to perform the impossible -- like incrementing a counter or any other modification of an already defined `<xsl:variable>`.

One indispensable use of `<xsl:for-each>` in XSLT 1.0 is to change the current document -- this is often needed in order to be able to use the `key()` function on a document, different from the current source XML document, for example to efficiently access lookup-table that resides in its own xml document.

On the other side, using `<xsl:template>` and `<xsl:apply-templates>` is much more powerful and elegant.

**Here are some of the most important differences between the two approaches**:

1. **`xsl:apply-templates` is much richer and deeper than `xsl:for-each`,** even
   simply because we don't know what code will be applied on the nodes of
   the selection -- in the general case this code will be different for
   different nodes of the node-list.
2. **The code that will be applied
   can be written way after the `xsl:apply template`s was written** and by
   people that do not know the original author.

**The [FXSL library](http://fxsl.sf.net)'s implementation of higher-order functions (HOF) in XSLT wouldn't be possible** if XSLT didn't have the `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction.

**Summary**: Templates and the `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction is how XSLT implements and deals with polymorphism.

**Reference**: See this whole thread: **http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200411/post60540.html**