# xslt to create comma-separated list from node attributes

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Export channel="XXX" date_stamp="20130113 01:01:01">
  <Script show_code="ALR" script_no="13081300" duration="1">
    <Product skn="222363" />
    <Product skn="203092" />
    <Product skn="219585" />
    <Product skn="201371" />
    <Product skn="201029" />
    <Product skn="202648" />
    <Product skn="201294" />
    <Product skn="201370" />
  </Script>
  <Script show_code="BQV" script_no="13081301" duration="1">
    <Product skn="400063" />
    <Product skn="203089" />
    <Product skn="212059" />
    <Product skn="202770" />
    <Product skn="400292" />
    <Product skn="400108" />
    <Product skn="400407" />
  </Script>
</Export>
```

And I would like to output (in simply text format) the Product @skn values as a comma separated entity. My current XSLT is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="no" media-type="text/xml" />

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="/EPGExport/Script">

    <xsl:value-of select="substring(@script_no,5,2)"/>/<xsl:value-of select="substring(@script_no,3,2)"/>/20<xsl:value-of select="substring(@script_no,1,2)"/><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(@script_no,7,2)"/>:00<xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@show_code"/><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Product/@skn"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will output as:

```
13/08/2013  00:00   ALR 222363

13/08/2013  01:00   BQV 400063
```

But I would like the last of the tab-separated values to output as:

```
13/08/2013  00:00   ALR 222363,203092,219585,201371,201029,202648,201294,201370

13/08/2013  01:00   BQV 400063,203089,212059,202770,400292,400108,400407
```

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just add a template for the `Product` element. In that template you can output each `@skn` and use the `position()` to determine if you need to add a comma or line return. Below is what I'm referring to.

You would add this template to your existing XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="Product">
  <xsl:value-of select="@skn"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

And then you would change the line:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Product/@skn"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
```

To this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Product"/>
```

And it will produce this output when run:

```
13/08/2013  00:00   ALR 222363,203092,219585,201371,201029,202648,201294,201370
13/08/2013  01:00   BQV 400063,203089,212059,202770,400292,400108,400407
```

Comment: I actually eventually resolved this myself yesterday using a nested for-each in the same way as suggested by ShaharB (I couldn't update this question at the time though) - however I prefer this template solution, it feels a bit neater. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you can switch to XSLT 2, it becomes trivial.

Replace

`<xsl:value-of select="Product/@skn"/>`

with

`<xsl:value-of select="Product/@skn" separator=","/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Matthew's answer, but instead of writing a new template, just write a nested for-each

So instead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="Product/@skn"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
```

use

```
<xsl:for-each select="Product">
   <xsl:value-of select="@skn"/>
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: [I would check out this question and answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158478/when-to-use-for-each-and-when-to-use-apply-templates-in-xslt) Using a `for-each` 'loop' isn't necessarily the best idea when you can just use `apply-templates` instead.