# How to transform a xml to html table using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

For example, I have an xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tests>
<testrun run="test1">
    <test name="foo" pass="true" />
    <test name="bar" pass="true" />
    <test name="baz" pass="true" />
</testrun>
<testrun run="test2">
    <test name="foo" pass="true" />
    <test name="bar" pass="false" />
    <test name="baz" pass="false" />
</testrun>
</tests>
```

If I transform it to a html with an xsl document, I may get an output as follows:

```
<html>
<body>test1<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td><td>Pass</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>foo</td><td>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bar</td><td>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>baz</td><td>true</td>
    </tr>
</table>test2<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td><td>Pass</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>foo</td><td>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bar</td><td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>baz</td><td>false</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

My question is the following:
How do I get this output:

```
<html>
<body>test1<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td><td>Pass</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>foo</td><td>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bar</td><td>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>baz</td><td>true</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

and this:

```
<html>
    <body>test2<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Test</td><td>Pass</td
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>foo</td><td>true</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bar</td><td>false</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>baz</td><td>false</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

how can i get it, is there anyone have opinions?

Comment: and i know that in the xslt 2.0 , it has result-document, and it can generate  mutli out file, but i don`t want to trans it to file, i want string or a OutputStream

Comment: With "multiple html strings" you mean multiple html files? There are two options. 1. call your xslt wiht an parameter to select the output for one file. Or use `document()` to create files form xslt

Comment: Than please add your your xslt attempt .

Comment: Well, which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use? The output of an `xsl:result-document` does not necessarily go to a file, you can set up your own resolver or handler, for instance with Saxon 9.7 see http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/lib/OutputURIResolver.html which serves for handling secondary result documents.

Comment: For XmlPrime, see http://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/doc/2.9/using-xslt.htm#multiple-result-documents on how to set up your code to handle `xsl:result-document`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the following would do the trick. I am not certain, what you mean by html strings though. If you need to output actual individual html documents, this will not suffice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<!-- This template is applied for each 'testrun' node in the xml document. It outputs the html, body and table tags and processes all children of the 'testrun' nodes according to any other templates.-->
    <xsl:template match="testrun">
      <hmtl>
       <body>
       <xsl:value-of select="@run"/>
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>            
        </table>
       </body>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

<!-- This template prevents that the 'tests' node is output, and makes sure that all child nodes of 'tests' nodes have matching templates applied to them. -->
    <xsl:template match="tests">
        <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

<!-- This template copies every single node from the xml without doing anything
other than making an exact copy. The other templates override this template.-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<!--This template makes sure that a table row with two cells with the values of the 'name' and 'pass' attributes of 'test' nodes are output for each 'test' node.-->
        <xsl:template match="test">
         <tr>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="@pass"/></td>
         </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

EDIT: Added explanation of the templates on request.

Comment: ok, thanks. but i am not very clear about your xslt, can you explain how do you select the second node <testrun> as output. and if i want all the <testrun> nodes, how do i do?

Comment: Added explanations of the templates on request. The most confusing thing, when learning xslt is understanding what 'apply-templates' does. There are some good posts about that here on Stackoverflow. This, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158478/when-to-use-for-each-and-when-to-use-apply-templates-in-xslt